# How do I get the Detail View Controller to show text relevant to the "cell" selected on the TableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

My storyboard contiains a Navigation Controller, a Table View Controller and a Detail View Controller. How do I get the Detail View Controller to show text relevant to the "cell" selected on the TableView?

I currently have my code set up so it will show an Image if a cell is selected. Like if "Cell 1" was selected it would show "Image 1" if "Cell 2" selected then it would show "Image 2" etc.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



//Create a couple UIImage objects
UIImage *firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];
UIImage *thirdImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"third.png"];

//Title of the view
self.title = charName;

//UIImageview based on characterNumber
switch (characterNumber) {
    case 0:
        CharacterImage.image = firstImage;
        break;

    case 1:
        CharacterImage.image = secondImage;
        break;

    case 2:
        CharacterImage.image = thirdImage;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

How do I do this but for text instead of images? So that when "Cell 1" is selected from the Table View Controller it would lead to the DetailViewController with scrollable text that would be different from the text that would show if the other cells were selected. Would I be using a "UITextView" and upload different .txt files? Thanks

So that when "Cell 1" is selected from the Table View Controller it would lead to the DetailViewController with scrollable text.

Comment: what is the text source exactly ? I mean for example you just want to pass a string and view it ?

Comment: yes you can use textviews and load different texts according to your tableView's cell selection. Actually you can make array of dictionaries containing the title to display in your tableView cell and details  of that title.

Comment: while populating your tableView cell, use [[dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"]; and when any row get selected pass the description [[dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"title"];and show that description inside your textView

Comment: @iVishal so I would be replacing the code for the UIImage? because it isn't what I need?

Comment: if you have images than good..but if you dont want to use images to make your build lighter, then you can use textViews..

Comment: @iVishal how do I use textviews instead?

Comment: replace imageViews with textViews, you have to write whole text from your images and take it into a string.

Comment: @user1677210 for what you are planning to do, the somewhat traditional way is you have an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary has key value pair for title and description, title you show it on tableview and description you show in detail viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Segue between the ViewControllers (ctrl+drag from one to another). Then add an identifier:

[image]

Then you need to call that from you didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and send the indexPath as number with it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Then you can get the number and add it to your new viewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSNumber*)indexNumber
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]){

        NSInteger index = [indexNumber integerValue];

        DetailViewController *detailView = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailView.textNumber = index;

    }
}
```

Of course you need to add a NSInteger textNumber to your DetailViewController. Then just check what NSInteger is selected and show different text.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard add a UIViewcontroller and connect it to your table view controller with command+drag, click to arrow and enter a segue name and choose push.

in your tableview controller.m

```
//#pragma mark - Table Did Select 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueNameGoesHere" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueNameGoesHere"])
    {
       DetailViewController *detailViewController  = [segue destinationViewController];
        //This will display on the Document Viewer
        detailViewController.fileText=@"What Ever your Text is"; // you can also select that text source from an nsmutablearray , a file or cloud solution but in that case you need to write a method that returns a string to you 
    }
}
```

in your detailview controller .h

```
@interface DetailviewViewController: UIViewController {
    UITextView *exampleTxt;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *fileText;
```

in your detailview controller.m

```
@synthesize fileText=_fileText

// you can create your textview in IB or programatically like below after that all you need to this set your text  
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad ];
    exampleTxt = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [exampleTxt setText:_fileText]; // look at here
    //[exampleTxt setColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //yes, it's deprecated, but works
    [self.view addSubview: exampleTxt];

}
```

If you dont like to add ui text view programatically, you can add it in IB. So to add TextView in IB follow this steps;

Go to your detail view controller on storyboard drag and drop a TextView in to your detailViewController;

detailviewController.h

```
@interface DetailviewViewController:  : UIViewController
{
    UITextView *textView;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextView *textView; 
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *fileText;
```

in your deatilviewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize textView=_textView;
@synthesize fileText=_fileText;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //[_textView setText:@"Your text"]; 
    [_textView setText:_fileText];
}
```

Comment: I understand that with this I do not need to add "TextView" on the storyboard right cause it is done programatically with under -(void)viewDidLoad on DetailViewController.m?

Comment: Yes you do not need add "TextView" on the storyboard. You alloc a textview  programatically and create its rectangle on x,y 100,100 and set it text to your string that you have passed to detailview controller in  `[exampleTxt setText:_fileText]` then finally you add it to view `[self.view addSubview: exampleTxt];`

Comment: I am getting an error when I select the cell from the tableview. Also, how do I set it to show different text for each cell selected?

Comment: what error do you get?  in here `detailViewController.fileText=@"What Ever your Text is";` this  sends @"What Ever your Text is" this is just an simple example you need a data source to send different strings for example use an NSMutablerray as a data source.